# How to join a few tables without repeat?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that left joins a few tables in different ways depending on a conditions.

```
SELECT
dh_partner.company_name,
dh_partner_abonnement.name,
dh_partner_abonnement.description,
dh_partner_abonnement.price,
dh_partner_abonnement.discount_price,
dh_studio.partner_id,
CONCAT('https://some.url/images/studio/logo/', dh_studio.logo) as logo_url,
CONCAT('https://some.url/studio/', dh_studio.alias) as page_url,
CONCAT('https://some.url/order/abonnement/', dh_studio.alias, '/', dh_partner_abonnement_studios.abonnement_id) as checkout_url
FROM dh_partner_abonnement
LEFT JOIN dh_partner on dh_partner.id = dh_partner_abonnement.partner_id
LEFT JOIN dh_studio on dh_studio.partner_id = dh_partner.id
LEFT JOIN dh_partner_abonnement_studios on dh_partner_abonnement_studios.studio_id = dh_studio.id
WHERE
dh_partner.status = 'active'
and dh_partner.id = dh_studio.partner_id
and dh_partner.city_id = '1'
and dh_partner_abonnement_studios.studio_id = dh_studio.id
and dh_studio.show_status = '1'
```

The challenge in the following code

```
CONCAT('https://some.url/ru/order/abonnement/', dh_studio.alias, '/', dh_partner_abonnement_studios.abonnement_id) as checkout_url
LEFT JOIN dh_partner_abonnement_studios on dh_partner_abonnement_studios.studio_id = dh_studio.id
and dh_partner_abonnement_studios.studio_id = dh_studio.id
```

It repeats to the each `dh_partner_abonnement` this column `dh_partner_abonnement_studios.abonnement_id`

I have to connect them correctly. I know that I need to use `if`, however having no idea how.

Comment: Use a correlated queries.

Comment: Show some sample result rows you are getting now and what you want to get instead.

Comment: BTW: Are you sure you really want to outer-join the tables? Wouldn't inner joins suffice? (Especially as you are dismissing any outer-joined records in your WHERE clause, anyway.)

Comment: Provide schema and relationship between each table. Also provide some sample data. **It repeats to the each dh_partner_abonnement this column dh_partner_abonnement_studios.abonnement_id** this is really not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing from the table names:

```
SELECT
  p.company_name,
  pa.name,
  pa.description,
  pa.price,
  pa.discount_price,
  s.partner_id,
  CONCAT('https://some.url/images/studio/logo/', s.logo) as logo_url,
  CONCAT('https://some.url/studio/', s.alias) as page_url,
  CONCAT('https://some.url/order/abonnement/', s.alias, '/', pa.abonnement_id)
    as checkout_url
FROM dh_partner_abonnement pa
JOIN dh_partner_abonnement_studios pas ON  pas.partner_id = pa.partner_id
                                       AND pas.abonnement_id = pa.abonnement_id
JOIN dh_studio s ON s.id = pas.studio_id
                 AND s.show_status = 1
JOIN dh_partner p ON  p.id = pa.partner_id
                  AND p.status = 'active'
                  AND p.city_id = 1
```

You haven't joined dh_partner_abonnement and dh_partner_abonnement_studios on the complete key, which should include the abonnement_id.

It also seems a studio has a partner_id to indicate that it belongs to a certain partner. However, in your query you are interested in the abbonement studios, so join the studio on the abbonement's studio_ids.